# How to form_later the user profile form to only allow 1 role to be assigned/removed

Tags: users, forms

I want to restict my site editors ( a role ) to only be able to select/deselect the role 'subscriber' and not be able to meddle with the other role assignments.  I have tried the following to remove the other roles :

```
case 'user_profile_form':
  global $user;
  if(in_array('site editor', $user->roles)  && !in_array('administrator', $user->roles)) {
    unset($form['account']['roles']['#options']['3']);  // administrator
    unset($form['account']['roles']['#options']['4']);  // site editor
  }
```

However this has the effect of both hiding the checkboxes and un-assigning the roles.  I want any existing assignments to these roles to persist.

Your help appreciated.

Comment: Roles are removed because when the form is submitted those roles are missing (and thus unchecked). You probably want to hide those options only, so that their value is still submitted.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I 'hide' the options ?

Answer (score 0):

Roles are removed because when the form is submitted those roles are missing (and thus unchecked). You can hide those options instead:

```
$form['account']['roles']['3'] = array(
  '#disabled' => TRUE,
  '#attributes' => array('class' => array('hidden'))
);
```

And some CSS `.hidden { display: none; }` or something.

> In D7+, form_process_checkboxes() and form_process_radios() already support you in doing so by allowing for partial sub-element pre-definitions [read more](https://www.drupal.org/node/342316#comment-4732130)

Comment: Ben,  I've just tried this ( without the CSS ) and although it successfully disables the checkbox it resets the role to unchecked upon form submission.

Comment: Oh, you need some processing server-side not to allow role changes then. Sorry that didn't work out :(

Comment: I think you're on the right track, #disabled should submit but the form structure is incomplete ( perhaps ).  Here's  dump of what I have when I #disable the test role and it loses its setting http://bit.ly/1FitMFJ.

Comment: Oh well, you could go quick-and-dirty-css-only

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing your own code, you may just want to use the Role Assign module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/roleassign